# How can I merge 2 DIV table rows in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-grid

In the below snippet I have 6 cells in 2 rows, but I need to merge cell number "2" and "5".

If doing it as a CSS Table DIV I know this can be done, but I like to do this the "Bootstrap way" (if any such exist), but have not been able find any documentation that I was able to get to work.

Anyone who knows how this can be done?

**The DIV:** (*Note that the snippet needs to be seen in expanded view for the cells to display the right way*)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card h-100" style="text-align: center">
      <h1>6</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nesting like this...

```
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card h-100 border" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>1</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card h-100 border" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>4</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row h-100 ">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card h-100 border" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>2 + 5</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card h-100 border" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card h-100 border" style="text-align: center">
                    <h1>6</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/6we5uiXzxl

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no clean way to resolve this using only Bootstrap 5 methods. You could make it work using `table`, as you wrote above. Or here is some mixed **Bootstrap 5 + display grid** way.

Here we are using `d-grid` - new BS5 class, and `gap-2` as grid gap BS5 support. For now the `d-grid` is poorly described in Bootstrap 5 documentation, [the only example of d-grid from BS5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/#block-buttons).

Note that `custuom-grid` and `custuom-grid-cell` are totally custom classes and doesn't belong to BS5.

Also can be usefull: [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) and [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) manual. Used them in the example below.

```css
.custuom-grid {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.custuom-grid-cell:nth-child(2) {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-grid gap-2 custuom-grid">
  <div class="custuom-grid-cell">
    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="custuom-grid-cell">
    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="custuom-grid-cell">
    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="custuom-grid-cell">
    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="custuom-grid-cell">
    <div class="card h-100 text-center">
      <h1>6</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```